# How to remove all elements of five from a list

Tags: python

My code for this returns 'None'.
In case my question is not clear if i take the list [1 , 3 , 4 , 5 ,5 , 7], I want the list [1 , 3 , 4 , 7] to be returned. My code is as follows:

```
print("This program takes a list of 5 items and removes all elements of 5: ")

    list4 = []
    list4.append(input("Please enter item 1:"))  
    list4.append(input('Please enter item 2:'))  
    list4.append(input('Please enter item 3:'))  
    list4.append(input('Please enter item 4:'))
    list4.append(input('Please enter item 5:'))
    def remove_five():
        while 5 in list4:
            list4.remove(5)
    print(remove_five())
```

Comment: What you read are strings. What you try to remove is an `int`. Also, your `remove_five()` function does not return anything.

Comment: You printed a method that returns nothing (so None)

Comment: `remove_five` doesn't return anything

Comment: I don't think anyone mentioned this yet but, `remove_five` doesn't return anything :-P

Comment: You are checking against an int. You need to check against a string '5'

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension might come handy this time.

```
num_list = [1 , 3 , 4 , 5 ,5 , 7]
num_list = [int(n) for n in num_list if int(n)!=5]
print(num_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 4, 7]
```

**N.B.:** Use casting for string variables like below:

```
num_list = [int(n) for n in num_list if int(n)!=5]
```

Comment: Use `map` instead: `[n for n in map(int, num_list) if n != 5]`

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints None because your function has no `return` statement.

If you printed like so you'd see the list unchanged because you have no `5`s in your list, you have `'5'` (a string)

```
remove_fives() 
print(list4)
```

If you want to add integers, not strings, you need to cast it

```
append(int(input
```

If you want to create a list of no fives, try list comprehension

```
no_fives = [x for x in list4 if x!=5]
```

Or keeping the input as strings

```
no_fives = [x for x in list4 if x!='5']
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
def remove_five():
    while 5 in list4:
        list4.remove(5)
```

to this:

```
def remove_five():
    while '5' in list4:
        list4.remove('5')
    return list4
```